# Why PHP function can't find item in_array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, global

I googled and search StackOverflow many times an read the whole PHP manual for `in_array()` but still stuck with what I thought it would be a very simple task.

So I have this array in my config.php file:

```
$page_access = array(
    'index' => array('1', '2', '3'),
    'users' => array('4', '5', '6')
);
```

In functions.php I have:

```
include 'config.php';

function level_access($page){
    global $page_access;
    if(in_array($page, $page_access)){
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}

level_access('index');
```

I expected to get "yes" as an output because then I would do something else in the function, but I'm stuck with a "no" output, no matter what I do.

I already tried a `print_r($page_access)` INSIDE the function just to check if it can read the array, and IT DOES return me the whole array (which means the function is reaching the outside array), but every time the answer to `in_array()` is NO.

Comment: Since `"index"` is a key in your array, you cannot use `in_array()` - because that's searching for values.

Comment: array_key_exists()is what youre looking for

Comment: You can use `array_key_exists()` PHP function to check if `$page` is in array or not.

Comment: array_key_exists() solved it! Thank you everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `in_array()` function for multidimensional array.
Instead, you can use `array_key_exists()` to check whether a key exists or not.

```
function level_access($page)
{
    global $page_access;
    if (array_key_exists($page, $page_access)) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`index` is the key of your sub-array, not its value `in_array()` will look for its values in the array, not its indexes.

You can use `array_key_exists()` or `isset()` instead. When using `isset()`, you check if the index of the array is set.

```
if (array_key_exists($page, $page_access)) {
    echo "yes";
}

// Or..

if (isset($page_access[$page])) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

- `isset()` will tell you if the index of the array is set, and its value is not null
- `array_key_exists()` will tell you definitively if the index exists in the array or not, even if the value is null or not

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/e2QMM).

That being said, usage of the `global` keyword is **discouraged**, and you should instead pass the variable as an argument to the function.

```
$page_access = array(
    'index' => array('1', '2', '3'),
    'users' => array('4', '5', '6')
);

function level_access($page, $page_access) {
    // Either isset() or array_key_exists() will do - read their docs for more info
    // if (array_key_exists($page, $page_access)) {
    if (isset($page_access[$page])) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}
level_access($page, $page_access);
```

See [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

- [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
- [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset)

Comment: array_key_exists() solved for me, thank you! Is there a way to remove global? The only other way of replacing it would be passing the array along when calling the function, correct?

Answer (score 0):

`index` is just a **key** in your `$pages_access` array. `in_array` checks the values.
To fix your code:

```
function level_access($page){
    global $page_access;
    if(in_array($page, array_keys($page_access))){
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for values by using `in_array()` you can't use that.
Rather use `array_key_exists()`.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!